# Делаю Gulp таски. Html возвращается, файл CSS - нет

Tags: css

```
            **Вот код.** 

                                           ` "use strict";


                                                const {src, dest} = require("gulp");
                                                const gulp = require("gulp");
                                                const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
                                                const cssbeautify = require("gulp-cssbeautify");
                                                const imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
                                                const plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
                                                const rename = require("gulp-rename");
                                                const rigger = require("gulp-rigger");
                                                const sass = require("gulp-sass");
                                                const removeComments = require("gulp-strip-css- 
                                             comments");
                                                const uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
                                                const panini = require("panini");
                                                const del = require("del");
                                                const browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();
                                                const cssnano = require("gulp-cssnano");


      var path = {
       build: {
            html: "dist/",
           js: "dist/assets/js/",
           css: "dist/assets/css/",
           images: "dist/assets/css/"
       },

       src: {
           html: "src/*.html",
          js: "src/assets/js/*.js",
          css: "src/assets/sass/style.scss",
          images: "src/assets/img/**/*.{.jpg,png,svg,gif,ico}"
        },
     watch: {
        html: "src/**/*.html",
        js: "src/assets/js/**/*.js",
        css: "src/assets/sass/**/*.scss",
        images: "src/assets/img/**/*.{.jpg,png,svg,gif,ico}"
     },

        clean: "./dist"
             }


         function html () {
        return src(path.src.html, { base: "src/" })
          .pipe(plumber())
           .pipe(dest(path.build.html));
                          }

      function css() {
      return src(path.src.css, { base: "src/assets/sass/" })
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browserslist: ['last 8 versions'],
        cascade: true
    }))
      .pipe(cssbeautify())
     .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
     .pipe(cssnano({
          zindex:false,
         discardComments: {
            removeAll:true

                }
               }))
    .pipe(removeComments())
    .pipe(rename())
            }

       exports.html = html;
        exports.css = css; `
```

Html возвращает норм, CSS не хочет.

10 раз пересмотрел уже все, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: я курс прохожу. src вроде бы везде указан. в функции CSS тоже указан. "{ base: "src/assets/sass/" }"

Comment: Возможно Вы правы...скажите что тогда поменять чтобы заработало. П.С. Тому видео около года.

Comment: приведите код в читаемый вид

Comment: Может у Вас есть возможность выделить именно ту строку / строки куда надо внимание обратить?